# Wrong length of reading file

Tags: c

I have the following text (D:/tst.txt):

```
blah
blah
blah
```

and I wrote the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    // read file to text
    char *path = "D:/tst.txt";
    FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");
    if(!f)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); 
    char *text = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    text[size] = '\0';
    fread(text, sizeof(char), size, f);
    fclose(f);
    // Test result
    printf("Size of text: %ld\n", size);
    printf("Text:\n");
    printf("%s", text);
}
```

Output:

```
Size of text: 16
Text:
blah
blah
blah══
```

Size is correct, because line ending is "\r\n". But text doesn't contain '\r' and it contains 2 garbage symbol.

Can I get correct text?

Comment: Try open the file in *binary* mode and see what happens.

Comment: On Windows `"r"` opens the file in translated text mode, which translates `\r\n` to `\n`. So try `"rb"` (binary, as suggested).

Comment: Thank you, "rb" works correct.

Comment: 1. `ftell()` always returns 'binary' length. 2. Better to cheek result of `fread()`, You will be informed about two bytes less

Comment: @JacekCz, any idea why ftell says16 when the file contains 18 bytes (blah\r\n=6*3)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I would guess that the last line does not contain \r\n. Otherwise the garbage characters would be printed in the next line.